# How to create a data frame from each url and then merge them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, url, web-scraping

I am trying to set up my code to create one dataframe from each url in a list and then combine these dataframes into a single dataframe.

I am very close to being done; however, as it is right now, my code shows this error message `cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid`

```
urls = ['url1', 'url2']
appended_data = []
for url in urls:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\bobby\OneDrive\Documents\MyPrograms\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    driver.get(url)

    tables = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)
    df = tables
    appended_data.append(df)
    driver.close()

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
appended_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\bobby\OneDrive\Documents\RecruitingApp\hopefullyit\test.csv')
```

I need help getting the code to create a df from each url and then combine them and write to csv.

Here is the complete error message

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-2-7451d5b1833d> in <module>
     11     driver.close()
      12 
 ---> 13 appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data)
     14 appended_data.to_csv(r'C:\Users\bobby\OneDrive\Documents\RecruitingApp\hopefullyit\test.csv')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in concat(objs, axis, join, join_axes, ignore_index, keys, levels, names, verify_integrity, sort, copy)
    226                        keys=keys, levels=levels, names=names,
    227                        verify_integrity=verify_integrity,
--> 228                        copy=copy, sort=sort)
    229     return op.get_result()
    230 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py in __init__(self, objs, axis, join, join_axes, keys, levels, names, ignore_index, verify_integrity, copy, sort)
    287                        ' only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel'
    288                        ' (deprecated) objs are valid'.format(type(obj)))
--> 289                 raise TypeError(msg)
     290 
    291             # consolidate

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only 
pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Comment: write each of them separately.

Comment: are you sure that the URL has the data? the problem is it doesn't find the data. Look at that it is telling you it's like an HTML tag `<class 'list'>`

Comment: which line makes problem? always put full error message (full Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you can keep all on list and convert to dataframe at the end - `DataFrame(list)` - without concatenate. Or you have to convert new list to DataFrame - `DataFrame(new_data)` - before you concatenate to DataFrame.

Comment: @KenrySanchez Yes I'm sure it is, I set it to print each dataframe before closing the driver to test and make sure

Comment: @furas sorry about that! I added the complete message

Comment: as you see in errror message - you have to convert `list` to `dataFrame` to concatenate it. `read_htmt` gives list of all tables in HTML, and you append it to list `appended_data` so you have 2-dimesional list. You can use `print(appended_data)` to see it.

Comment: maybe you should get only one `df` from list `tables` - ie. `df = tables[0]`

Comment: If @furas is right, so you just need to `df = tables[0]` if you are only waiting for just one table.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html @furas has right. You are getting a list of data frames. You must ask for the right index fo the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @furas and I are saying, `pandas read_html` retrieve a list of Data frames from the URL source. So you just need to ask for the appropriate index of the list. If you only retrieve just one table, you can ask for the index.

```
 df = tables[0]
 appended_data.append(df)
 driver.close()
```

Comment: Sorry for being slow but I'm not following.  I had tried that previously indexing the list at [0] and it only printed or wrote one of my url data to the .csv file.  But what I'm trying to do is write all of the data I get from the urls them to that single .csv.

Comment: Ok. Now I understand better. Well, if you have more than one table in the list of dataFrames,  you can create a loop and then try to append to a new DataFrame. Do you have more than just one table on the list?

Comment: Remember. You have one too many URLs and we are saying that every URL has just one table. if it is, that ok much be fine, but if you have more than one table or if you sometimes have more than just one table. You had better create a loop for that situation. Try to analyze it and then come back. It will be more easily for us.

Comment: Look at these examples. https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/101351/pandas.read_html

Comment: Ok thanks that helps a lot.  But yes there is more than one table in the list, there is one table per URL.  Each time the code runs it will get the table from its respective URL and then append it to the list `appended_data`.  When I ONLY try to print `appended_data` after the loop it is exactly how I want it. The problem then arises when I try to use `to.csv` because it is a list and not a dataframe.  What I'm not clear on is what is the best way to write that info to a .csv without losing the formatting?